# QT installer framework - How to add a custom script after online update execution

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Can I add some code after the maintance tool update execution(or after the final page)?

Basically I have an application that is already in use. It has a setuped QT Installer Framework autoupdates. And I need to execute a script right after a new update will be installed. But that script does not exist yet in the current installed version - it will be added by that update.

I have a class UpdateManager.cpp:

```
// ... Manually check for updates ...
// ...
arguments << "--script=installer-noninteractive.qs";
QProcess::startDetached("./uninstall", arguments);
// Quit the app
```

Where the **installer-noninteractive.qs** is done using [this official guide](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html)

As I got the only entrypoint for me to interupt the end of update is this script. But when the maintaince tool is running it basically has an old version of script, because it will be downloaded after.

Comment: Rather than have the installer run that script, can your application call it the first time it's run?

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but it will be better if I can run it post update